# coldfusion 9 using cfsearch on verity returns -1705 error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8, verity, cfsearch

I've created a collection in verity, but when I use cfsearch on it I get this error:

```
Message: There was a problem executing the cfSearch tag with the following collections.

Detail: Collection (status code): asktheexpert (-1705)
```

I have restarted the search service to no avail.

any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather from various googling, this indicates some sort of index corruption, and in general people never really worked out why.  But if you purge & reindex your collection, it *should* go away.

I haven't used Verity in an age, but my experiences that most "weird errors" (one of which was this very one) were "solved" with a purge/reindex.

Ref: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2006/4/5/Verity-1-Me-1705  (and others along a similar vein, but Ray's probably the most reliable).

Are you in a position to migrate away from Verity?  It's dead technology and will be dropped from CF in the next release.  It might be a good idea to think about migrating to Solr if you haven't already got plans afoot to do so.

EDIT:
Another thing I've read today about this is that it might crop up when the collection is using one language, and the index and/or search are using different languages.  Given you're transporting code between dev & prod, perhaps just verify that the collection language is the same as the index & search language.

Other than that - and my suggestions below about destroying various bits and pieces and starting again :-/ - I'm out of ideas.

Comment: purging has done nothing, it still comes back with a -1705.... it might be a case i'll have to switch to solr.  the problem is on my development server this index works fine, but as soon as i move it to my live server it all falls apart.

Comment: Damn, sorry.  What about if you blow the collection away completely, recreate, and reindex?  It sounds like drastic advice but this seems like a fairly transient error, and - for the life of me - I cannot find any better suggestions.  Am still searching...

Comment: Actually, hold on.  Perhaps just try to reinstall the connector? On a multi-server install the deinstall/reinstall batch files are in JRun4/verity, and will probably be in the cfusion/verity dir or similar on a stand-alone install.

Comment: OK, well in that case perhaps just blow the collection away and reindex.